# unhosted website I'm building needs an instagram client ID

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api, clientid

I am currently in the middle of developing a website. Right now, it's hosted on my local server. It's pretty far from being ready for deployment, but I want to build out the client's instagram feed. I know I need to register to get the client ID, but it will not accept blank or localhost as a URL so I'm not sure how to start building this out. It seems odd that you would need a hosted website to BEGIN building out the functionality of something like this. Maybe I'm missing something? Thanks in advance!

Ruby/Rails by the way.

Comment: Do they not have a sandbox?

Comment: alright! cool! I have no idea what you're referring to. can you point me to some info?

Comment: Typically services that offer an api also give you a test environment the you can use during your development phase. That's often called a sandbox. If you know the domain or IP of the server that will run your application when it's done, use that to register. Then just ist the api key locally and see she happens. This works for stuff like Google maps. It will warn, but works. Same thing might happen here. If not search for the text, staging or  sandbox area in the docs.

Comment: ok, thanks, I will look into that. I guess it looks like either way the client will need to have decided on a domain name and have that purchased to begin developing then?